# What is the difference between IDRAC, IPMI and ILO?

Tags: ipmi, drac

I sometimes hear my colleagues talking about `iDRAC, IPMI and iLO`, when restarting a server. It seems that those terms are often misused.

For instance, is there a difference between saying that you connect to `IPMI and iDRAC`?

If I well-understand, `iDRAC and iLO` are ipmi-based tools respectively implemented by `Dell and HP`, bringing new functionalities?

Comment: Dell's iDrac has security issues too, do not connect them internet facing, use them only on your private network.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

These are all forms of **[out-of-band management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management)**. IPMI is a standard. DRAC is a proprietary offering from Dell. ILO is the HP ProLiant variant. ILOM for Sun/Oracle. In some cases, you may hear the terms used interchangeably.

The proprietary lights-out management solutions provide more integration with the hardware and often time have nicer features (monitoring, logging, access) than a generic IPMI implementation.

Answer (score 23):

I would like to point out that **IPMI** or **Intelligent Platform Management Interface** 
is an open, industry-standard interface that was designed for the management of server systems over network. It enables you to monitor and control your server platform, as well as to retrieve information about your server platform is a standard. It supports FRU inventory reporting, system monitoring, logging of system events, system recovery (system reset or power off) or alerting.

But what is more important is that all of the aforementioned service processors - iDRAC, iLO or ILOM - are compliant with this standard (or with a specific version of it) so you can either use vendor specific tools to communicate with them or standardized IPMI tools. This may be an advantage when you need to integrate the platform with some monitoring system which supports IPMI standard but not a specific service processor.

Comment: IPMI has security issues https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-207A and https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2013/07/02/a-penetration-testers-guide-to-ipmi

Comment: @davenpcj That was in 2013, we are in 2017 now...

Comment: @inf3rno no we aren't.

Answer (score 8):

Old question but ... ;

- IPMI     - Intelligent Platform Management Interface ( General Standard )
- IDRAC - Integrated Dell Remote Access ( Dell )
- ILO -  Integrated Lights-Out ( HP )
- IMM - Integrated Management Module  ( IBM )

These  embedded server management technologies  allow a system administrator to monitor and manage servers and other network attached equipment by remote control regardless of whether the machine is powered on or whether an operating system is installed or functional.

For laymen, they are similar but for technical people  they are different.
So pls dont use them interchangebly if you are troubleshooting faulty hardware.
Be specific.

Comment: +1 "pls dont use them interchangebly if you are troubleshooting faulty hardware. Be specific."